# KeyError while dropping labels in Pandas Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataset in CSV loaded into a data frame. I would like to show the highest correlations between columns (Top 10 Negative and Top 10 Positive)

I cam across a code on this website that I thought would help me -

```
def get_redundant_pairs(df):
    '''Get diagonal and lower triangular pairs of correlation matrix'''
    pairs_to_drop = set()
    cols = df.columns
    for i in range(0, df.shape[1]):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
             pairs_to_drop.add((cols[i], cols[j]))
    return pairs_to_drop


def get_top_abs_correlations(df, n=5):
    au_corr = df.corr().abs().unstack()
    labels_to_drop = get_redundant_pairs(df)
    au_corr = au_corr.drop(labels=labels_to_drop).sort_values(ascending=False)
    return au_corr[0:n]
```

I call this function from my DataFrame -

```
train = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/DSF_HW3_Datasets/train.csv')
get_top_abs_correlations(train.loc[:, train.columns != 'Id'],10)
```

I get a KeyError Value -

```
KeyError: 'Foundation'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
....
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in get_loc(self, key, method)
   2404 
   2405         if keylen == self.nlevels and self.is_unique: 
-> 2406             return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2407 
   2408         # -- partial selection or non-unique index

 pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine.get_loc()

 KeyError: ('Foundation', 'OverallQual')
```

How do i fix this error? Train.csv file - https://pastebin.com/vTh6md5W

Answer (score 1):

You want mask/nlargest:

```
# get the correlation matrix
corr = df.corr()

# mask away the lower triangle and diagonal
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr),1) == 1

# get the upper triangle (excluding diagonal) by masking and stack:
corr = corr.where(mask).stack()

# 10 largest by absolute values
max10 = corr.abs().nlargest(10)
```

Output (max10):

```
GarageCars    GarageArea      0.882475
YearBuilt     GarageYrBlt     0.825667
GrLivArea     TotRmsAbvGrd    0.825489
TotalBsmtSF   1stFlrSF        0.819530
OverallQual   SalePrice       0.790982
GrLivArea     SalePrice       0.708624
2ndFlrSF      GrLivArea       0.687501
BedroomAbvGr  TotRmsAbvGrd    0.676620
BsmtFinSF1    BsmtFullBath    0.649212
YearRemodAdd  GarageYrBlt     0.642277
dtype: float64
```

To get the original (signed) correlations:

```
corr.loc[max10.index]
```

which coincidentally is the same with the absolute max.